# Does .zip compression internally maintain a checksum?

Tags: unix, zip

Does a .zip archive internally maintain a checksum for the files in it?

If it maintains a checksum, how can I be sure the checksum is verified during decompression? And is it possible to verify the checksum without decompressing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, zip holds CRC-32 checksum for each file in archive, and it should verify it during the decompression.

Comment: How can I verify .zip files without decompressing..in unix .?

Comment: This is not possible, since file entries contain CRC-32 of uncompressed data, so you should decompress them anyway.

Comment: There is `unzip -t` to do the verification without writing the uncompressed data to disk, which is probably what @sachinjose wants.